# PHP - Merge more than 2 arrays

Tags: php

I'm trying to make the values in the `EVENTNAME` array the key of the arrays below it.

I want to be able to do a foreach on on a php variable and get the `EVENTNAME` and the count for its IMMIGRATIONS, EFFECTS and SUPPLYCHAINS.

```
$keyevents = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT EVENTNAME FROM KEYEVENTS GROUP BY EVENTNAME");
oci_execute($keyevents);
oci_fetch_all($keyevents, $keyevent);

$immigrations = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) IMMIGRATIONS FROM KEYEVENTS LEFT JOIN IMMIGRATION ON KEYEVENTS.EVENTID = IMMIGRATION.EVENTID GROUP BY EVENTNAME");
oci_execute($immigrations);
oci_fetch_all($immigrations, $imm);

$effects = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) EFFECTS FROM KEYEVENTS LEFT JOIN EFFECT ON KEYEVENTS.EVENTID = EFFECT.EVENTID GROUP BY EVENTNAME");
oci_execute($effects);
oci_fetch_all($effects, $eff);

$supplychains = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) SUPPLYCHAINS FROM KEYEVENTS LEFT JOIN SUPPLYCHAINS ON KEYEVENTS.EVENTID = SUPPLYCHAINS.EVENTID GROUP BY EVENTNAME");
oci_execute($supplychains);
oci_fetch_all($supplychains, $supp);

$stats = array_merge($keyevent, $imm, $eff, $supp);

highlight_string("<?php\n\$stats =\n" . var_export($stats, true) . ";\n?>");
```

**var_export**

```
array (
  'EVENTNAME' => 
  array (
    0 => 'Brexit',
    1 => 'leave date set',
    2 => 'leave date ',
    3 => 'deal or no deal',
  ),
  'IMMIGRATIONS' => 
  array (
    0 => '1',
    1 => '1',
    2 => '1',
    3 => '1',
  ),
  'EFFECTS' => 
  array (
    0 => '2',
    1 => '1',
    2 => '1',
    3 => '2',
  ),
  'SUPPLYCHAINS' => 
  array (
    0 => '1',
    1 => '1',
    2 => '1',
    3 => '1',
  ),
)
```

[image: Output of $Stats]

Comment: Don't post images of text! Copy paste it just like anything else. Preferably a var_export so that we can use the output. Also what is your expected output from that array?

Comment: I was hoping to get '(First val in EVENTNAME array)' => array((First val from Immigrations array), (First val from Effects array), (First val from SupplyChains array))

Comment: Sounds simple enough. Just post that var_export and I can give you an answer

Comment: Added the var_export

Comment: This looks like something that could be better done in one SQL query (rather than the 4 you have), to give you a usable array right out of `oci_fetch_all()`.

Comment: I tried doing that but kept running into errors or the counts were wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you don't know the key names and use array_keys to figure it out.
Then I loop the first subarray and use the key in array_column to get the other values.
Your expected output does not include associative keys in the subarray, but if you need it use the second code.

```
$arr = array ( 'EVENTNAME' => array ( 0 => 'Brexit', 1 => 'leave date set', 2 => 'leave date ', 3 => 'deal or no deal', ), 'IMMIGRATIONS' => array ( 0 => '1', 1 => '1', 2 => '1', 3 => '1', ), 'EFFECTS' => array ( 0 => '2', 1 => '1', 2 => '1', 3 => '2', ), 'SUPPLYCHAINS' => array ( 0 => '1', 1 => '1', 2 => '1', 3 => '1', ), );
$keys = array_keys($arr);

foreach($arr[$keys[0]] as $key => $val){
    $result[$val] = array_column(array_slice($arr,1), $key);
}

var_export($result)
```

Output:

```
array (
  'Brexit' => 
  array (
    0 => '1',
    1 => '2',
    2 => '1',
  ),
  'leave date set' => 
  array (
    0 => '1',
    1 => '1',
    2 => '1',
  ),
  'leave date ' => 
  array (
    0 => '1',
    1 => '1',
    2 => '1',
  ),
  'deal or no deal' => 
  array (
    0 => '1',
    1 => '2',
    2 => '1',
  ),
)
```

https://3v4l.org/Seteg

---

```
$keys = array_keys($arr);

foreach($arr[$keys[0]] as $key => $val){
    $result[$val] = array_combine(array_slice($keys, 1), array_column(array_slice($arr,1), $key));
}

var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'Brexit' => 
  array (
    'IMMIGRATIONS' => '1',
    'EFFECTS' => '2',
    'SUPPLYCHAINS' => '1',
  ),
  'leave date set' => 
  array (
    'IMMIGRATIONS' => '1',
    'EFFECTS' => '1',
    'SUPPLYCHAINS' => '1',
  ),
  'leave date ' => 
  array (
    'IMMIGRATIONS' => '1',
    'EFFECTS' => '1',
    'SUPPLYCHAINS' => '1',
  ),
  'deal or no deal' => 
  array (
    'IMMIGRATIONS' => '1',
    'EFFECTS' => '2',
    'SUPPLYCHAINS' => '1',
  ),
)
```

https://3v4l.org/aPCub